# Unable to install numpy on docker python3.7-slim in a raspberry pi

Tags: python, docker, numpy, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to deploy a small microservice in a new Raspberry pi 4 b over docker. This service is currently working just fine on my windows pc and I'm even able to locally run the service into the pi.
So far I've been able to trace down the error to the numpy installation when creating a docker image.

```
Collecting numpy==1.19.1
  Downloading numpy-1.19.1.zip (7.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: still running...
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpts0hfzam
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ozdo_kbb/numpy
    Complete output (226 lines):
    Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pxd.in
    Processing numpy/random/_sfc64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_philox.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_mt19937.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pyx.in
    Processing numpy/random/_pcg64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/mtrand.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/bit_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_common.pyx
```

I believe that the important piece of information is shown later and which tells me that I'm not able to compile some of the numpy's libraries.

```
creating build/src.linux-armv7l-3.7/numpy/distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifc
    Could not locate executable lf95
    Could not locate executable pgfortran
    Could not locate executable f90
    Could not locate executable f77
    Could not locate executable fort
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable g95
    Could not locate executable pathf95
    Could not locate executable nagfor
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
    Running from numpy source directory.
    setup.py:470: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
```

*How to replicate:*
**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .

RUN apt-get update \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

**requirements.txt:**

```
numpy==1.19.1
```

Similar posts have shown some progress by adding a couple of more instructions to the Dockerfile but I see no improvement

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade  \
    && apt-get install libc-dev -y \
    && apt-get install libatlas-base-dev -y \
    && pip install --pre numpy \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

The slim image doesn't have the tools for compiling numpy. You have to install them before trying installing numpy.

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .


RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        make \
        gcc \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt \
    && apt-get remove -y --purge make gcc build-essential \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Lines after the `pip install -r requirements.txt` clean building tools.

It should work better.

Another solution is to use the `python:3.7` image instead of `python:3.7-slim`.

**Edit**
Some links about numpy on aarch64:

- [Issue on conda repo](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8297) for supporting aarch64,
- [miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge) building packages with conda on other architecture than x86_64.

**edit**
a working solution given by the OP in comment:

```
FROM python:3.7-stretch

WORKDIR /usr/src/app COPY . .

RUN apt-get update \ 
    && apt-get install build-essential make gcc -y \
    && apt-get install dpkg-dev -y \ 
    && apt-get install libjpeg-dev -y \ 
    && pip install -r requirements.txt \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir . \
    && apt-get remove -y --purge make gcc build-essential \
    && apt-get auto-remove -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && find /usr/local/lib/python3.7 -name "*.pyc" -type f -delete
```

Comment: Thanks, it was part of the problem and allowed me to see a different error message. Not too bad. I still don't see how the same Dockerfile using Python3.7:slim runs smoothly on my windows PC but crashed on my rasberry...
I cannot tell you that it fixed my problem but it did help a bit thanks!

Comment: This is the same docker image but not the same processor architecture (x86_64 on windows and ARM on raspberry). It doesn't seem to be easy to install numpy on ARM architecture. I update my answer with some links.

Comment: Completely forgot to add the final version that made it all running.
`
FROM python:3.7-stretch
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .

RUN apt-get update \
     && apt-get install build-essential make gcc -y \
     && apt-get install dpkg-dev -y \
     && apt-get install libjpeg-dev -y \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir . \
     && apt-get remove -y --purge make gcc build-essential \
    && apt-get auto-remove -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && find /usr/local/lib/python3.7 -name "*.pyc" -type f -delete
`